# Angular Material mdTabs - how to get only the effect of tabs animation not the content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I want to get the animation effect of when someone clicks on the tab and the border below that tab slides to right with the button having a nice ripple effect. I don't want to use the content inside the tab, I just want the tab effect.

[image: mdTabs]

As you can see, clicking on the second tab will make the border slide to the right but content will also move to left. I only want tab button sliding to the right as part of my effect. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the md-tabs directive without the contents:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.10.0/angular-material.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.css">

<md-content ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
  <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="selectedIndex">
    <md-tab label="one"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="two"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="three"></md-tab>
  </md-tabs>
  <div layout layout-align="center center">{{ selectedIndex }}</div>
</md-content>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I'm just wondering, can we track the selectedIndex then and show content and use animation classes `.ng-enter` etc. to animate the views ? I'm trying to achieve same effect as this website one: https://stemn.com/

Comment: You can see in their code that they added the `ui-sref` directives to the `<md-tab>`'s so when you click the tab labels the state changes.

Answer (score 19):

You can add this in styles

```
[role="tabpanel"] {
    transition: none;
}
```

Comment: I tried using your logic but it is not working. I also tried with following code still unable to remove transition.  
md-tabs-content-wrapper, *[role="tabpanel"] {
          transition: none;
      }
Any other ideas? Thanks for help.

Comment: Works for me 1.6.6