# AngularMaterial Tabs showing only 1st tab

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, angular-material, dropdown

Why are `md-tabs` showing only the first tab? The rest of them appears after I click in the tabs area.

First tab looks like this:

[image: only 1 tab]

After clicking in the tab area:

[image: all tabs]

My code looks like this:

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
    <md-tab label="Home"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Profile"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Messages"></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

On purpose I left the content of tabs empty because I want to get rid of the transition animation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31768849/1075289).

One of the problems could be that the tabs are in [bootstrap dropdown menu](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp).

Thank you for your ideas!

**EDIT**

I have just found out that the tabs has troubles even without bootstrap when using them in `md-menu`.

Comment: Can you add any Fiddle/Plnkr?

Comment: @KhalidHussain Sorry, I am trying to remove the bootstrap to see what is going on.

Comment: are you trying to place your `md-tabs` within `bootstrap's dropdown` ??
If yes , may I ask why ??

You can change which `tab` is selected by using `md-seleted` attribute of `md-tabs` to keep a specific `md-tab` within `md-tabs` selected.

Refer this : http://codepen.io/Rishii/pen/MyrVoz

Comment: @Rishab777 Yes, I need a dropdown form. That's why I need the tabs in in the bootstrap dropdown or in md-menu. Without both of these the tabs are working like a charm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you solved it yet?

I'm having the same problem except that my angular tabs is in bootstrap's modal.
When I click on a button to toggle the modal it only show the first tab until I click on it.

After doing some testing it appears that I could work around by hiding the angular tabs with ng-show and show it after a small amount of delay.

```
<button ng-click="controller.showTabs()">Show Tab</button>


<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom ng-show="show_tab">
    <md-tab label="Home"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Profile"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Messages"></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Controller's function when user clicks on the drop down / button to toggle the modal:

```
this.showTabs = 
function()
{
    //250ms delay
    $timeout(function()
    {
        $scope.show_tab = true;
    },250);
}
```

Comment: In the end we didn't use the material tabs. I'll accept the answer, hope it will help somebody. Thank you.