# disable the slide in / out animation that occurs when the selected tab changes in angularjs v1.5

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Hello I have created an tab template from angular material tab template. When I select any tab it slides in / out. I want to disable that animation.

```
<md-content class="md-padding">
<md-tabs class="md-accent" md-selected="data.selectedIndex" md-align-tabs="{{data.bottom ? 'bottom' : 'top'}}">
  <md-tab id="tab1">
    <md-tab-label>Item One</md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body>
      View for Item #1 <br/>
      data.selectedIndex = 0;
    </md-tab-body>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab id="tab2" >
    <md-tab-label>item2</md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body>
      View for Item #2 <br/>
      data.selectedIndex = 1;
    </md-tab-body>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab id="tab3">
    <md-tab-label>Item Three</md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body>
      View for Item #3 <br/>
      data.selectedIndex = 2;
    </md-tab-body>
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Material mdTabs - how to get only the effect of tabs animation not the content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768789/angular-material-mdtabs-how-to-get-only-the-effect-of-tabs-animation-not-the-c)

Answer (score 1):

We can disable it by using

> @.disabled

property which is introduced in Angular 4.3.1. Add code to your component

> @Hostbinding('@.disabled') disabled = true

or in your html `<div [@.disabled]="expression"></div>`

Refer to @lokeshdaiyas comment on https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2706

Comment: plz be aware that this breaks the sidenav component in case you are using it